# how to Skip None holding tuple in list?

Tags: python, list

I want to filter out all tuples consisting only of None-elements from a list, so for this this list

```
listobj = [(None, None, None, None), (None, None, None, None), (None, None, None, None),(None,None,'01/02/2015','25'),(None,None,'01/02/2015',None),(0,None,None,None)]
```

I want output like that:

```
  listobj = [(None,None,'01/02/2015','25'),(None,None,'01/02/2015',None),(0,None,None,None)]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> [x for x in listobj if any(y is not None for y in x)]
[(None, None, '01/02/2015', '25'), (None, None, '01/02/2015', None), (0, None, None, None)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
listobj= [i for i in listobj if i.count(None)<len(i)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it has to be a cool one-liner, but here's one very basic approach:

```
def noneSeq(seq):
  """Helper function that determines if seq is all None."""
  for x in seq:
    if x is not None: return False
  return True

a = [x for x in listobj if not noneSeq(x)]
```

This gives:

```
[(None, None, '01/02/2015', '25'), (None, None, '01/02/2015', None),
 (0, None, None, None)]
```